# Can NuGet update all projects when it gets a newer version for one project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I have just added a package to a newer project, and its version has increased. Now I would like to have all the projects that use that package use the newer version. Is it possible for NuGet or a script to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In solution node, select 'Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions' in context menu.

For each package, click 'Manage' button and choose project to use this package.

Then update package in 'Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions' window, packages are updated for all projects.